# Can not ssh to google computer engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have create vm on [gce](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute/), but I can not ssh:

My server:
[image]
ssh from brower gcloud command:

`ssh: connect to host 104.199.125.15 port 22: Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors for troubleshooting hints.`

my firewall:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I have add [router](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/routes) and everything ok
[image]